# What is the best library for implementing Tab Navigation (dynamic content) in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am building a basic news App where different tabs will have dynamic news under it. I want suggestion which is the best library available for this.

I tried few library but navigation from one tab to another is not smooth and add some jerkiness.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`react-navigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-based-navigation.html) library for tab navigation, drawer navigation etc

Answer (score 0):

Actually the tab navigation was moved out of `react-navigation` and now is packaged under `react-navigation-tab`

Usage: `import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';`